# Typescript type error is not getting fixed by type narrowing

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a type called `Level` and its numbers are between 1 and 6 (both 1 and 6 included).
I have another list of number which is between 1 and 8 i have a function which accepts Level
I tried to narrow the type but didn't got fixed:

```js
type Level = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6;

onSelect={(level: number) => {
  // level is between number 1 to 8 but the setHeading function bellow accepts an object with a level key that it's type is Level 
  if ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].includes(level)) {
    editor.commands.setHeading({
      level,
    });
  } else if (level === 7) {
    editor.commands.setParagraph();
  }
}}
```

There shouldn't be any errors because i narrowed the `level` to `Level` but in VS Code i get an error which says:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Level'.ts(2322)
heading.d.ts(16, 17): The expected type comes from property 'level' which is declared here on type '{ level: Level; }'
```

I tried to narrow the `level` and get everything working but i still get the same error.

Comment: please provide minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.includes` method was written without any [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates). This means it has no narrowing capabilities and leaves the types of its inputs untouched.

You would have to write your own type guard which wrappes the `includes` logic.

```
const isLevel = (level: number): level is Level => {
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].includes(level)
}

const onSelect =(level: number) => {
  if (isLevel(level)) {
    setHeading({
      level,
    });
  } 
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhBuEA2UC8UCMUA+UBMOUAzIQCyECshAbANwBQjAxgPYB2AzsFBxMABIQAhgBMAlmwDmaKAAohAJ0kAuKAG8oSBMlVxEKAL4BKNAD51BxvVadu7AMrIITbqllb9qtgFcAtgCMIBRNUczV6KCgxADM5MQ49ZHdtJCMTcMjI3gFhcSlZDMzIj2QAGgjM4wZIgyh6S2t2LiiElJlkzygfAKCjVRKUeNg20PUKyIU+bwU2KABtDFL8JaIl0iWKJeoAXQA6CSYkbxEIDg7kI3qgA)